# (MySQL)Need to get match scores from multiple tables and sort by the sum of their scores

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the MATCH AGAINST scores from multiple tables with a common key and combine their sums.  The goal in the end is to create a search algorithm that will return rows with matching group_IDs.  I have built a mysql query that has yet to run without error.

In case you want to know, this is the specific error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource

These are the tables I wish to search:

---

### table: jn_groups

> group_ID, name

---

### table: jn_chat

> chat_ID, group_ID, name

---

### table: jn_events

> event_ID, group_ID, title, description

---

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    g.group_ID AS group_ID,
    g.name AS name,
    SUM(gscore + cscore + escore) AS score,
    MATCH(g.name) AGAINST (" . $query . "') AS gscore,
    MATCH(c.name) AGAINST (" . $query . "') AS cscore,
    MATCH(e.title,e.description) AGAINST (" . $query . "') AS escore 
FROM jn_groups g 
LEFT JOIN jn_chat c ON g.group_ID = c.group_ID 
LEFT JOIN jn_events e ON g.group_ID = e.group_ID 
WHERE 
    MATCH(g.name) AGAINST (" . $query . "') 
    OR MATCH(c.name) AGAINST (" . $query . "')
    OR MATCH(e.title,e.description) AGAINST (" . $query . "') 
ORDER BY score
```

Any help making a query similar to that run would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How does `$query` look like? Is there just a string in this variable?

Comment: Print out the generated SQL produced from PHP (i.e. the fully concatenated version).  Then run this sql directly against the database.  It should become more obvious what the problem is.  As everyone else points out, without knowing what's in the `$query` variable, it's impossible for us to advise you, without having to revert to guesswork.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, yeah, it is just a search algorithm, so aside from fringe cases and reserved characters, $query should just be a string, so "Hello World" would be a fine replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things which could be the reason for breaking this query:

**variable `$query`**

All your AGAINST-operators end with **`"'`**, but start only with **`"`**. Make sure `$query` contains

- valid data and
- start with an **`'`**.

**Summate the partial results**

Your `SUM` won't work, because it doesn't know `gscore`, `cscore` and `escore`. It will look for field names instead. You can change this part of your statement like this (ofc replace *`hello world`* with your desired search term):

```
....
SUM(
    (MATCH(g.name) AGAINST ('hello world'))
    + (MATCH(c.name) AGAINST ('hello world'))
    + (MATCH(e.title,e.description) AGAINST ('hello world'))
) AS score,
....
```

Two advices:

- Try running the query against your database with a SQL 
  tool first (p.e. SQLyog, MySQL Workbench, phpMyAdmin or similar), to see if it is working like you want it to. There are a few other possibilities how to break this (p.e. no or wrong fulltext index definition, wrong field names and such), so you have better control about whats going wrong.
- Be careful when using reserved variables like `NAME` in field names. Either escape them properly or - in my eyes better - avoid them.

Comment: Awesome! That SUM combination worked like a charm, looking back on it I do see how using a SUM in that way was illogical.  Also, good catch on the missing ' single quotes, I did not spot that.  Once I put in those two changes the whole search algorithm worked instantly.  I didn't realize "name" can be reserved, I will keep that in mind.  Thanks for the help Bjoern!